# Project to nearest point on convex polytope

Tags: iterative-method, computational-geometry, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, projection

I have a point $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a convex polytope $\mathcal{P}$ given as the intersection of half-spaces:

$$\mathcal{P} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid a_1 \cdot x \le b_1, \dots, a_n \cdot x \le b_n\}.$$

I would like to project $y$ onto the polytope, i.e., to find the nearest point $z \in \mathcal{P}$: in other words, to minimize $\|y-z\|_2$ subject to $z \in \mathcal{P}$.  I know there are algorithms using quadratic programming, but I am hoping for a simple to implement method, even if it is not optimal.

Here is one possible incremental method: pick the halfspace that $y$ is furthest from, i.e., find the index $i$ that maximizes $a_i \cdot y - b_i$, then project $y$ onto that halfspace, i.e., replace $y$ with $y' = y - (a_i \cdot y - b_i) a_i$, and repeat.  (I have assumed, without loss of generality, the inequalities have been normalized so $\|a_i\|_2=1$.)  While this might not yield the optimal solution, I hope that after it a fixed number of iterations it will get close to the optimal solution.

Is this a good method?  Is there a better method that is simple to implement and does reasonably well?

Comment: Have you implemented and tested this? It sounds reasonable but sometimes playing around a little bit helps to get insight.

Comment: Also potentially answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433298/distance-from-a-point-to-a-polyhedron-or-to-a-polygon . Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi distance algorithm might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @hardmath, good call, thank you!  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $y$ is not in the polyhedron (it is easy to check whether it is, and we know that the distance is zero in that case). If $y$ is outside then the closest point will be on the surface of the polyhedron.

So I came up with the following (horrible) algorithm, which will give you an upper bound. Let $y^0=y$.

1. Find distance of point $y^n$ to all planes $a_i\cdot x = b_i$.
2. Pick the closest one, save the distance, project $y$ on the plane and get $y^{n+1}$.
3. Remove the plane from the list for the purposes of steps 1 and 2.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 with until $y^{n+1}$ is inside the polyhedron.

The sum of the distances you saved during the process will be the upper bound. <del>Since it is a convex polyhedron, this algorithm should terminate in at most 5 iteration</del>. *I am not so sure about this last claim, so I am going to remove it*.

You can also potentially compute the distance between $y$ and $y^{n+1}$ to get a better upper bound.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting ideas.  How well does this work?  For instance, does it always terminate?  Does it give a good approximation?  If we stop it early, does it give a good approximation?  The algorithm I listed in the question finds the *farthest* plane and projects to that, whereas your answer proposes to find the *nearest* plane, but is otherwise very similar.  What's the rationale for picking the nearest plane rather than the farthest plane?  If we stop early after a fixed number of iterations, I suspect what I proposed will be better, but I haven't tried to check that.

Comment: For most cases, this will terminate faster than your suggestion. Both our suggestions should terminate, at worst, in (number of faces of polyhedron) iterations. However, the thing I cannot prove, with either your suggestion or mine, is whether $y'$ will be on or in the polyhedron when the algorithm stops. I could not create a counter-example so I am going to hypothesize that it will be, but I don't know. Good approximation, maybe not but can't say, with either algorithm. Mine will (at least, should) give an upper bound always, yours might find a lower bound sometimes. That is my rationale.